# Duplicate messages received via SMS

Tags: ios, sms, duplicates

I was testing a call to the Messages app from my app (using `MFMessageComposeViewController`) and when I chose myself as the recipient I noticed that I got the message back 4 times.

At first I thought I had done something wrong, but upon further testing of the Messages app, it appears it always sends duplicates (randomly 2 to 4 times) when sending to myself.

I've tried researching the issue but I keep getting too many unrelated results.  Is this a known issue with `iOS`?  I can see how it might have something to do with `iMessage`.  It's very odd behavior, especially in that it's not always a consistent number of replies.

Anyway, is this something I should worry about with my app?  Seems out of my scope since Messages is handling it, and I doubt my users will be texting themselves.

Code I'm using:

```
if(message.length > 160) {
    message = [message substringToIndex:157];
    message = [message stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
}

MFMessageComposeViewController *messageVC = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
[messageVC setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
[messageVC setBody:message];
[self presentViewController:messageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please post the related code. I done this before, but I didn't get any such behavior so, I thinks there should be something wrong in your code.

Comment: Added my code, but like I said this is occurring when I just open Apple's Messages app by itself (without my app even running).